# How to retrieve saved SQL import task when Integration Services not installed

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

I've just inherited a 2008R2 instance with a few jobs (scheduled jobs that execute various ssis packages) which are failing.

I want to export the .dtsx packages concerned from MSDB so I can troubleshoot them in Visual Studio, however, I can't connect to integration services to get at them, because its not installed!

I'm also unable to use DTUTIL at command prompt, because I get an error that Integration Services is not installed!

User says these pacakges were created as import/export jobs and saved to SQL Server (not file system) which appears to be the case.

I can see the packages by querying the msdb.dbo.sysssispackages table.

First question, is how have these been saved to SQL Server MSDB when SSIS isn't even enabled?

Secondly, how can I get at those pesky dtsx files?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use dtutil on any other computer that has 2008R2 integration services service installed. Otherwise, write an SSIS package to export the binary data from `msdb.dbo.sysssispackages`

Comment: I use this script to retrieve SSIS package data: `use msdb; select name, cast(cast( packagedata as varbinary(max)) as XML) from dbo.sysssispackages`

Comment: That's a great tip gofr1.